# If a then function doesn't return a promise, why the next then will be run immediately?

Tags: javascript, promise

Inside of a then() function, if I didn't return a promise but calling the function directly.

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  doSomethingElse(); //I know I should return doSomethingElse()
}).then(finalHandler);
```

I know `doSomethingElse & finalHandler` will run in parallel then instead of running sequentially. But I am still not sure why is that exactly?

```
doSomething
|-----------------|
                  doSomethingElse(undefined)
                  |------------------|
                  finalHandler(undefined)
                  |------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run code in a `.then()` handler, you get the following design choices:

**1. Return nothing.**  That leaves the return value `undefined` and that is a signal to the parent promise that there is no additional asynchronous operation to wait for here so the promise chain can continue running the next steps in the chain.

**2. Return a promise.**  This tells the parent promise that you want to "insert" a promise into the chain and the following `.then()` handlers should not be called until this promise is resolved.  The chain will essentially wait for this promise.  If this new promise is ultimately resolved, the next `.then()` handler will get called.  If this new promise is ultimately rejected, the next `.catch()` handler will get called.

**3. Throw an exception.**  This tells the parent promise that the operation in the `.then()` handler failed and the parent promise chain immediately becomes rejected and the next `.catch()` handler will get called.

So, in your case, if `doSomethingElse()` is an asynchronous operation and you don't return a promise that is connected with that asynchronous operation, then you've just "branched" your promise chain into two separate chains.  The main parent chain will continue calling the next `.then()` handler because you returned nothing.  Meanwhile, your `doSomethingElse()` function is essentially its own parallel promise chain.  It could even have it's own `.then()` handlers as in:

```
 doSomethingElse().then(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

That would just be a completely separate promise chain that would have no connection at all to the other promise chain except for the timing of when this other promise chain was started.  Once it starts, it runs independently from the other chain.  This is typically referred to as "branching" in promise terminology.  You branch into a new chain.  The two run separate form one another.  If both branches use asynchronous operations (which they presumably do), those asynchronous operations would be interleaved and both in flight at the same time.  The timing of when they both finished would be completely indeterminate (since they have no programmatic relationship in their timing).

Branching to a completely independent promise chain like this is usually a programming error and some promise implementations may report a likely programming error in the console.  The reason this is usually an error is there is no way for anyone outside this code to have any way to monitor or catch errors in the branched and independent promise.  And promises without error handling are bad.  They eat errors silently.

There are certain cases where you legitimately don't change your program behavior if an error happens.  Often times when you're closing a file at the end of a long sequence or even just trying to close files after errors have occurred, you just want to make your best efforts to close the file and you don't really have anything more useful to do if the close fails (except perhaps log the failure) so there's no particular reason to try to propagate back that type of failure.  But, this should only be done in a very thoughtful way.  99.9999% of the time, errors should be propagated back to the caller and creating a new branched and independent promise chain like this does not propagate its errors back anywhere so it's usually not the right coding strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not need to return a `Promise`. If nothing was explicitly returned, by default `undefined` is returned. Functions in Javascript work like that. See the example

```js
function doSomething() {

}

console.log(doSomething());
```

When you return a `Promise` from the function in the `then` chains, `then` will work only if the returned `Promise` is resolved. If an exception was occurred, the `catch` function will work if the last exists.
So actually your code is like

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  doSomethingElse();
  return undefined;
}).then(finalHandler); `undefined` is passed into the `finalHandler` function
```

What about the parallel, they will work not in parallel, but sequentially if the code is `then(...).then(...)`. These `then` work sequentially. But if your `doSomethingElse` also returns a `Promise`, it will have its own sequence of chain. It's flow is independent from the `doSomething` flow.

Comment: Hi, both your answer & @jfriend00's answer made me understand my problem. I marked his answer accepted because he also mentioned the throw case that expands my understanding. I am really sorry. :(

Comment: @Qiulang Nice answer. Nothing to worry